# Talking during intercourse inherits aphonia and looking at genitalia inherits blindness?

Tags: sex, authenticity

> Narrated by Abi Hurairah that the prophet PBUH said: If one of you got engaged in intercourse, they shouldn't look at the genital for that inherits blindness, and not talk too much for that inherits aphonia (lack of the ability to talk).

This hadith is listed at the Islam-critical website [WikiIslam.net](https://wikiislam.net/wiki/Qur%27an,_Hadith_and_Scholars:Islamic_Silliness), and described as "Hadith translated by FFI forum member".  At the [Faith Freedom International (FFI)](http://forum09.faithfreedom.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=3751&start=0) forum, it is listed in Arabic as:

> عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال : قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم : إذا جامع أحدكم فلا ينظر إلى الفرج فإنه يورث العمى ولا يكثر الكلام فإنه يورث الخرس

From a scientific standpoint this doesn't make any sense at all. We are commanded to believe in the hadiths, but how can I believe in something that is just a lie and contradictory?

Comment: Can you give reference to the specific hadith or where you got it from?

Comment: How do you know it's not scientifically valid? Do you mean there's a study for people who did this and their children didn't have any issue? Kindly provide proof. (Additionally from what I understand these instructions are not binary, but they do affect the fetus to *some* extent. Sometimes it makes the child blind sometimes it isn't). I'm not saying it's correct, only that your question doesn't support your claim. Perhaps if you link a study that have been conducted on blind children or aphonia children's parents...then maybe we can conclude better

Answer (score 3):

Established Saheeh narrations and tradition states that spouses may freely look at each other's private parts, and that is the consensus of most schools of thought. The Hadith you have quoted is classed is fabricated. From [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/3801):

> **It is permissible for a woman to see all of her husband’s body and for
>   a man to see all of his wife’s body**, with no need to go into details,
>   because Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning): “And those who
>   guard their chastity (i.e., private parts, from illegal sexual acts),
>   except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right
>   hands possess, - for then, they are free from blame; but whoever seeks
>   beyond that, then those are the transgressors.” [al-Mu’minoon 23:5-7]
>
> (Fataawa al-Mar’ah by Ibn ‘Uthaymeen, 121).
>
> Al-Bukhaari reported in his Saheeh (no. 250) that ‘Aa’ishah said: “The
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)and I used to bathe
>   from one vessel.”
>
> Al-Haafiz said in al-Fath: “Al-Daawoodi interpreted this to mean that
>   it is permissible for a man to look at his wife’s ‘awrah and
>   vice-versa. This is supported by the report narrated by Ibn Hibbaan
>   via Sulaymaan ibn Moosa, who was asked about a man looking at his
>   wife’s private parts. He said: ‘I asked ‘Aa’ishah, and she referred to
>   this hadeeth.’ This is evidence in this matter. And Allaah knows
>   best.”
>
> I say: as for the words that some people attribute to the Prophet
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), that it is makrooh
>   (disliked) for a man to look at his wife’s private parts, this is not
>   saheeh. This includes the reports narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas and Abu
>   Hurayrah according to which the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah
>   be upon him) said, “When any one of you has intercourse with his wife,
>   let him not look at her private parts, because this causes blindness,
>   and let him not speak, because this causes muteness.” Ibn al-Jawzi
>   said: **“(This is) mawdoo’ (fabricated).”** (See al-Mawdoo’aat by Ibn
>   al-Jawzi, 2/271-272).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, scientifically this does not make any sense. Marriage gave the right of intercourse, how would be the looking at genitalia for married couple is prohibited. It is also not correct from Islamic view.

Please see the following article translated 
[Ruling on looking at the husband and wife's genitalia](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=ar&sl=ar&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fislamqa.info%2Far%2F153538)